# Deploying Native C/C++ Binary as a standalone Microservice in PCF-DEV

Tags: c, microservices, executable, cloud-foundry, binaryfiles

I have a use case to deploy a compiled  Native C executable as a Microservice on PCF:

The compiled executable is called like so: 
    "mycbinary inputfile outputfile"
and terminates after the operation. The Microservice is thus not an LRP.
It is possibly a Task in PCF palance, but it does not rely on the existence of other Microservices.
It must be a standalone Microservice but not a long-running one.

How can I achieve this use case with PCF please, i.e what possibilities do I have?
The Microservice terminates when the binary is done with its work until it is needed again.

To test the feasibility of what I could do, I tried pushing some compiled C code to PCF-DEV.
I am using cf push since that's my understanding of a standalone App on PCF

cf push HelloServiceAgain -c './helloworld' -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/binary-buildpack.git -u process --no-route

The push crashed with the following message:

Waiting for app to start...
Start unsuccessful

TIP: use 'cf.exe logs HelloService --recent' for more information

In the log file there was this entry:
    OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"

Then I pushed another command which expects parameters. This started without a problem, but the same message in the log file

cf push HelloServiceGCC -c 'gcc -o ./hellogcc ./hello1.c' -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/binary-buildpack.git -u process --no-route

I have the following additional questions please:

1) Is the message "Process has crashed with type: "web" an ERROR? And why is the command called multiple times?
 2) The second push which succeeded is supposed to create a compiled `hellogcc` executable which I expect to see in the same root directory. Where is the output file created and how can I access it from the local file system?

Sorry for asking so many questions but I am a newbie in the PCF business.

Comment: `And why is the command called multiple times?` -> when your app "crashes" (in your case it's exiting cause it's supposed to, but the platform considers that a crash), the platform will attempt to rectify the situation and restart your app. In your case, that just results in the command running multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

> The Microservice is thus not an LRP. It is possibly a Task in PCF palance, but it does not rely on the existence of other Microservices. It must be a standalone Microservice but not a long-running one.

It's definitely a task. It's fine that it does not rely on other services. A task is just simple a process that runs for a finite amount of time and exits 0 for success or something else for error.

> cf push HelloServiceAgain -c './helloworld' -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/binary-buildpack.git -u process --no-route

I would recommend using this slight variation:  `cf push HelloServiceAgain -c 'sleep 5000' -b binary_buildpack -u process --no-route`.

This will...

1. Assume that the compiled binary is in the current directory.
2. Uses the system provided binary buildpack which should be fine.
3. Sets the health check to be based on the process & sets no route.
4. Runs `sleep`, which is merely to pass the health check.

The purpose of this is so that your application will upload & stage. We set the command to `sleep` because we just need the app to stage and start (this is a workaround to make sure that staging occurs, you have to run once to trigger staging at least at the moment). Once the app starts, just run `cf stop` and stop the app. Since all you have is the task, you don't need the app to continue running. If you update your app, you do need to follow this process again though, as that will restage your changes.

At this point, you can `cf run-task` and execute your program. Ex: `cf run-task app-name './helloworld'`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks again for the good clarifications. I stumbled upon the Spring Cloud Task which seems to fulfil my requirements, so I am trying that option. My Plan is to use the ProcessBuilder to call my binary in the CommandLineRunner. However, I am not sure of the command to call.

Comment: How does Cloud Foundry know the location of my binary when the command is called?

Comment: While Spring Cloud Task is a wonderful project, IMO that is overkill. You don't need to wrap your nice, efficient native executable in a JVM just to get it to run. You can run it directly. If you need some set up or massaging, you can wrap it in a powershell or batch script. Side note, the Java buildpack is focused only on running Java apps on Linux. It would be difficult to get a Java app to run on a Windows Cell in Cloud Foundry.

Comment: `How does Cloud Foundry know the location of my binary when the command is called?` -> It's not Cloud Foundry. It's just how you execute processes on Windows. You can specify the full path to the executable, you can specify a relative path or you can leave off the path and make sure it's on the search PATH. When you push your app to CF, the target of push (usually the current directory, unless you set `-p`) will be the current working directory from which your application runs. Thus if your binary is in the target directory, `./helloworld` should work. If it's in a `bin/` then `bin/helloworld`

Comment: `While Spring Cloud Task is a wonderful project, IMO that is overkill.`--> Well explained. I will try the suggestion of wrapping `it in a powershell or batch script`. But then, it should run as a _Task_ and not as a *LRP*. I guess a I can do it like you suggested in a previous post (`push it as a normal app, stop the app, run a run-task`). Iam not providing snippets because we are writing the technical concepts and prototyping the use cases beforehand. Thanks once again!

Comment: I created a manifest.yml with the command to call the simple binary like so:
`command: ./helloworld && sleep infinity` with the usual elements `no-route: true` and  `health-check-type: process`. The command was called once and container was subsequently destroyed, which was exactly my use case. So I really don't need the Spring Cloud Task like you pointed out, thanks.

Comment: However, I called another binary which converts a file type into another file type. Apparently, that also worked because the output says file with name was created. **BUT**, I can't see the file in the execution directly. How can I locate the created File please? A simple command like `gcc -o hellocompiled hello.c && sleep infinity` also worked but there was no `hellocompiled` in the base directory like I'd expected. Do I need to mount external Volumes for this and similar scenarios where files must be written to disc to work?

Comment: Files will only be around for the duration of your container. If it runs, and stops quickly that could be problematic. You'd really need a three phased approach: run, ship to somewhere stable (S3, NFS, etc..), then exit.

Comment: Alright, I thought as much. But still  kind of annoying going extra steps when all you need is the output to your base directory. But thanks for your reply, I am really learning a lot from you...